# jansson-change json value in file

Tags: c, json, file, key-value, jansson

I have a json file. And, the file is successfully loaded.
but, i would like to change the value such as below
and save the json file with the modification.
But, the value is not changed and saved at all.
How could i do?

from /home/pi/desktop/test.json

```
{
"new_one": 1,
"new_two" : "do not",
"new_three" : true
}
```

to /home/pi/desktop/test.json

```
{
"new_one": 234,
"new_two" : "do",
"new_three" : false
}
```

So, i did

```
int main()
{

     json_t *json;
    json_error_t error;
    char *pos;

    json_t *obj = json_object();

    int rc =0 ;
    json = json_load_file("./test.json", 0, &error);

    if (!json)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "process : json error on line %d: %s\n", error.line, error.text);
        rc = 1;
    }

    const char *key;
    json_t *value;

    void *iter = json_object_iter( json );

    while( iter )
    {
        key = json_object_iter_key(iter);
        value = json_object_iter_value(iter);
        if(!strcmp(key, "new_one")){
            printf("Change Value\n" );
                json_object_set(iter, "new_one", json_integer(1234)); 
            }
        if(!strcmp(key, "new_three")){
            printf("Change Value\n" );
                json_object_set(iter, "new_three", json_string("alert")); 
            }

        iter = json_object_iter_next(json, iter);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: json object returned by json_load_file() is completely in RAM memory, and does not contain any association to the file any more. So all changes to json object are made to memory only (not to the file). You need to write modified json object to a file. So, Lavra's answer is correct.

Comment: this is what i need thanks

Comment: Pretty sure you should be using json_object_set_new - this code has a memory leak using json_object_set on an anonymous object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a call to `json_dump_file()`, which will save your modified JSON contents to file.
So, after your while() loop, add this:

```
rc = json_dump_file(json, "./test.json", 0);
if (rc) {
    fprintf(stderr, "cannot save json to file\n");
}
```